# Requests to Oracle through Simple Ebean are slower than via RawSQL

Tags: oracle, ebean

I have a model mapped to Oracle table. ( I simplified it below)

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "my_scheme", name = "TEST")
public class Test extends Model {
@Id    
@Column(name = "ID")
public Long id;

@Column(name = "VALUE")
public String value;

@Column(name = "TESTDATE")
public DateTime date;

....

}
```

Table has 1 billion of records.

If i do search by Value - it works similar between RawSQL approach and Simple ebean query.

But if I need to search by date range, Raw SQL wins.
Because in raw sql I put

```
"TESTDATE >= TO_DATE('"+startDate+"','yyyy/MM/dd') and TESTDATE < TO_DATE('"+ endDate +"','yyyy/MM/dd')
```

and ebean generates sql based on it with this TO_DATE functions

But if I do similar stuff with ebean query

```
Test.find.where().query.and(Expr.ge("date", startDate), Expr.lt("date", nextDate)).findPagingList...
```

, in logs I can see that ebean generated:

```
TESTDATE >= 2014-01-21 00:00:00.0 and TESTDATE < 2014-01-22 00:00:00.0
```

And for some reason the request takes way more time.

UPD:
The only way to tell ebean to use to_date using query, that I found:

```
Expr.and(Expr.raw("date >= to_date(?,'yyyy/MM/dd')", startDate), Expr.raw("date < to_date(?,'yyyy/MM/dd')", endDate))
```

Comment: That last fragment is not even valid SQL.

Comment: Yeah, it's not valid, but that's how ebean shows it in the log

Comment: I'm interested.  What is "way more time." ? The TO_DATE sql is not going to use bind values so there is a difference in the statements there.  Why don't you post up the 2 actual SQL statements executed?